# Not able to install mysql-devel on CentOS-7

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python, python-3.5

On CentOS 7 The below error is reported when I do an
yum install mysql-devel. Ultimately I want to install mysqlclient by resolving this first. Would Appreciate any help on this.Thanks.Python version is 3.5.

```
    Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
    Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
     * base: centos.bhs.mirrors.ovh.net
     * epel: ny-mirrors.evowise.com
     * extras: centos.bhs.mirrors.ovh.net
     * ius: mirror.symnds.com
     * remi-safe: remi.check-update.co.uk
     * updates: centos.bhs.mirrors.ovh.net
     * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
    Resolving Dependencies
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package mariadb101u-devel.x86_64 1:10.1.14-2.ius.centos7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: mariadb101u-libs(x86-64) = 1:10.1.14-2.ius.centos7 for package: 1:mariadb101u-devel-10.1.14-2.ius.centos7.x86_64
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package mariadb101u-libs.x86_64 1:10.1.14-2.ius.centos7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: mariadb101u-common(x86-64) = 1:10.1.14-2.ius.centos7 for package: 1:mariadb101u-libs-10.1.14-2.ius.centos7.x86_64
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package mariadb101u-common.x86_64 1:10.1.14-2.ius.centos7 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: mariadb101u-config(x86-64) = 1:10.1.14-2.ius.centos7 for package: 1:mariadb101u-common-10.1.14-2.ius.centos7.x86_64
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package mariadb101u-config.x86_64 1:10.1.14-2.ius.centos7 will be installed
    --> Finished Dependency Resolution

    Dependencies Resolved

    ==============================================================================================================================
     Package                            Arch                   Version                                  Repository           Size
    ==============================================================================================================================
    Installing:
     mariadb101u-devel                  x86_64                 1:10.1.14-2.ius.centos7                  ius                 913 k
    Installing for dependencies:
     mariadb101u-common                 x86_64                 1:10.1.14-2.ius.centos7                  ius                  60 k
     mariadb101u-config                 x86_64                 1:10.1.14-2.ius.centos7                  ius                  23 k
     mariadb101u-libs                   x86_64                 1:10.1.14-2.ius.centos7                  ius                 634 k

    Transaction Summary
    ==============================================================================================================================
    Install  1 Package (+3 Dependent packages)

    Total size: 1.6 M
    Installed size: 7.7 M
    Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
    Downloading packages:
    Running transaction check
    Running transaction test


    Transaction check error:
      file /etc/my.cnf from install of mariadb101u-config-1:10.1.14-2.ius.centos7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-server-5.6.31-2.el7.x86_64
      file /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18 from install of mariadb101u-libs-1:10.1.14-2.ius.centos7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-libs-5.6.31-2.el7.x86_64
      file /usr/bin/mysql_config from install of mariadb101u-devel-1:10.1.14-2.ius.centos7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-client-5.6.31-2.el7.x86_64
      file /usr/bin/mysql_config-64 from install of mariadb101u-devel-1:10.1.14-2.ius.centos7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-community-client-5.6.31-2.el7.x86_64

    Error Summary

-------------
```

Comment: What yum repository was `mysql-community` installed from? You would want to install all the MySql apps from the same repo. Best thing may be to remove the previous install (if possible) and re-install from one repo. Should be pretty quick, just back up any config and data files first.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did the following and it got resolved:yum install mysql-community-devel and pip3 install mysqlclient

Answer (score 8):

instead of "yum install mysql-devel" do "yum install mysql-community-devel"